# List index out of range in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to this and I tried googling but
I can't seem to fix this error inside "fingersUp" function.

Basically, each part of a finger has indexes and this function checks if the thumb finger is up based on these indexes. Each finger has 4 points.

I'm using PyCharm and Python 3.8, if that helps.

```
if self.lmList[self.tipIds[0]][1] > self.lmList[self.tipIds[0] -  1][1]: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's the full code:

```
    import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
import math
import numpy as np

class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.tipIds = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                    self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):
        xList = []
        yList = []
        bbox = []
        self.lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                xList.append(cx)
                yList.append(cy)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                self.lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
            if draw:
                cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

                xmin, xmax = min(xList), max(xList)
                ymin, ymax = min(yList), max(yList)
                bbox = xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax

            if draw:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (xmin - 20, ymin - 20), (xmax + 20, ymax + 20),
                (0, 255, 0), 2)

        return self.lmList, bbox

    def fingersUp(self):
        fingers = []
        # Thumb
        if self.lmList[self.tipIds[0]][1] > self.lmList[self.tipIds[0] - 1][1]:
            fingers.append(1)
        else:
            fingers.append(0)

        # Fingers
        for id in range(1, 5):

            if self.lmList[self.tipIds[id]][2] < self.lmList[self.tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)

    # totalFingers = fingers.count(1)

        return fingers

    def findDistance(self, p1, p2, img, draw=True,r=15, t=3):
        x1, y1 = self.lmList[p1][1:]
        x2, y2 = self.lmList[p2][1:]
        cx, cy = (x1 + x2) // 2, (y1 + y2) // 2

        if draw:
            cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), t)
            cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), r, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (x2, y2), r, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), r, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            length = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)

        return length, img, [x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy]

def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:

            cTime = time.time()
            fps = 1 / (cTime -  pTime)
            pTime = cTime

            cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
            (255, 0, 255), 3)

            cv2.imshow("Image", img)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__ == "__main_":
    main()
```

Comment: The error means 'you tried to access a list index which doesn't exist'.  Break your condition down bit by bit and see exactly which index is out of range

Comment: I would add `print(self.lmList)` and `print(self.tipIds)` before the offending line to see what the problem is.

Comment: @2e0byo there are 4 points for the thumb, here we're taking the 3rd point

Comment: @Zephyrus my comment (now deleted) came from poorly formatted error code which suggested that you were looking up an index like `this[0] - > ]` which is invalid syntax.  I deleted it when I saw that the code is syntactically correct below.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def fingersUp(self):
    fingers = []
    if len(self.lmList):
        if self.lmList[self.tipIds[0]][1] > self.lmList[self.tipIds[0]-1][1]:
            fingers.append(1)
        else:
            fingers.append(0)

        for id in range(1,5):
            if self.lmList[self.tipIds[id]][2]< self.lmList[self.tipIds[id]-2][2]:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)
    else:
        fingers = [0,0,0,0,0]
    return fingers
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue. Once adding Try: Except: around the if else statements in the fingersUp function I had no issue. The error is there because the fuction is being run even when your hands are off the screen.

```
 Try:
        if self.lmList[self.tipIds[0]][1] > self.lmList[self.tipIds[0] - 1][1]:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)
 Except: 
        fingers.append(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try, this line:**

- the brackets aren't placed right that is why it shows the error.

```
if (self.lmList[self.tipIds[0][1]]
```

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iwD4.png)

1.Indentation
2. Missing "_ "

Comment: Please assume that I am blind and that my screen reader cannot handle your picture of text. Most of the information of your answer is missing in that situation.